# Capturing regex expression in Phantom.js returning null

Tags: javascript, regex, phantomjs

I'm trying to scrape from the following [website](http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/f/favorde01.html)

Specifically, I'm trying to obtain the player's draft position, aka "X overall" which appears in the line

> 1st round (3rd pick, 3rd overall)

Within my `page.open()` function, I call

```
var rawText = page.plainText;
var regExp = /pick, ([\d]+)\w\w overall/;
var matches = regExp.exec(rawText);
console.log(matches);
```

However, matches is returning as null

Comment: You can use `/pick, (\d+)\w{2} overall/i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex seems fine (the match below works) so there must be something wrong with the string you're matching against.

```js
console.log("1st round (3rd pick, 3rd overall)".match(/pick, ([\d]+)\w\w overall/));
```

Comment: You're right, it appears that the `page.plainText` doesn't include the target string